# How to make left side (original code) of monaco diff editor editable?

Tags: diff, monaco-editor

I'm searching for a possibility to edit the code of both sides - left and right - in monaco diff editor.

I've tried already this:

```
var originalModel = monaco.editor.createModel("heLLo world!", "text/plain");
var modifiedModel = monaco.editor.createModel("hello orlando!", "text/plain");

var diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(
  document.getElementById("container"), 
  { readOnly: false }
);

diffEditor.setModel({
    original: originalModel,
    modified: modifiedModel
});
```

But that (readOnly) option effects just the right side, which is by default editable.

Here is a demo link:
[creating-the-diffeditor-hello-diff-world](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-diffeditor-hello-diff-world)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Having the same issue.

Comment: wataash found a solution, thanks and respect to him

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `originalEditable: true` in [`IDiffEditorOptions`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.idiffeditoroptions.html#originaleditable):

```js
var originalModel = monaco.editor.createModel("heLLo world!", "text/plain");
var modifiedModel = monaco.editor.createModel("hello orlando!", "text/plain");

var diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById("container"), {
    originalEditable: true, // for left pane
    readOnly: true,         // for right pane
});
diffEditor.setModel({
    original: originalModel,
    modified: modifiedModel
});
```